Как провести нулевую плоскость/отображение пересечения нуля на 3D-графике matplotlib?
Мне необходимо отобразить либо полупрозрачную плоскость 0 по оси z, либо, что лучше, отобразить как-нибудь ярко само пересечение с 0 все в той же плоскости. Как мне лучше это сделать? Можно ли это вообще сделать?


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Возьмите за правило предоставлять свой код в вопросе в тестовом виде для воспроизведения проблемы. Не следует нарушать правила сайта - вопрос могут закрыть.

Есть метод contour в matplotlib. На примере параболоида (после координат мэша идет level - смотрите документацию):
...
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=.5)
ax.contour(X,Y,Z,[0],colors='red',linewidths=1)
...


Нужно заметить, что matplotlib это не настоящий 3d-движок. поэтому, возможно, для подобных задач имеет смысл рассмотреть какую-то другую библиотеку.
